# Pode-se criar variáveis dentro de um bloco e utilizá-las depois?

Tags: variáveis, lua, declaração-de-variável

```
do
   local a2 = 2*a
   local d = sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*c)
   x1 = (-b + d)/a2
   x2 = (-b - d)/a2
end          -- scope of `a2' and `d' ends here
print(x1, x2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, elas são acessíveis porque se você não disser que a variável é local então ela é implicitamente global. Quando usa uma variável não declarada antes, e não foi usado `local` é uma declaração de variável que pode ser acessada em todo o código.

Alguns consideram isso um erro e que não deveria ser usado (sempre tem lá sua utilidade), mas eu evitaria. Fiz um exemplo criando uma variável local com escopo mais amplo e deixei a outra global, para mostrar que funciona e é igual. Eu sempre optaria por declarar a variável local antes de usá-la e quando precisa dela em escopo mais amplo, declare nesse escopo antes de usar pela primeira vez. Assim:

```
local a = 2
local b = 6
local c = 4
local x1
do
   local a2 = 2 * a
   local d = math.sqrt(b ^ 2 - 4 * a * c)
   x1 = (-b + d) / a2
   x2 = (-b - d) / a2
end
print(x1, x2)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/DEvZ2u). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ykewpwvc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/Scope.lua).

Comment: Obrigada Maniero, seu comentário foi esclarecedor.

Answer (score 1):

Variaveis `a2` e `d` são locais nesse bloco e não podes usar fora, porque estão declarada como local:

```
local a2 = 2*a
local d = sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*c)
```

Variáveis `x1` e `x2` são globais porque não tem a tag de local antes por isso deves poder usar depois:

```
x1 = (-b + d)/a2
x2 = (-b - d)/a2
```

Comment: Entendi! Obrigada Pbras!